# Javascript: Excuting 2 functions in desired interval

Tags: javascript, timer, setinterval, intervals

I'm quite new to javascript and I'm trying to learn time events. I'm trying to implement a function which takes a **number** and execute `function1` for that **number** of times, then execute `function2`. But between each execution, I'd like to have a set interval. E.g., `function1` prints "foo" and `function2` prints "bar". If the function's input number is "3" & interval is 5 seconds, the final printing should be foo,foo,foo,bar,foo,foo,foo,bar .... with each 5 seconds apart.
I've tried `for` loop and `while` loop.

```
var i=0;
while (i < 4){//number of times to repeat "function"
    if (i%4 == 0){
        setInterval(function(){
            console.log("bar");
        },2000);//interval between functions
    }
    else{
        setInterval(function(){
            console.log("foo");
        },2000);//interval
    }
    i++;
    if (i==4) i = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function fooBar(foo,delay){
    var i=1;
    setInterval(function(){
        if (i%(foo+1) ==0){
            console.log("BAR");
        }
        else {
            console.log("foo");
        }
        i++;
        //set i back to 0. not necessary, though
        if (i==(foo+1)){
            i=0;
        } 
    },delay);
}
fooBar(3,1000);//number of "foo"s , delay in ms
```

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple things you missed.

1. `setInterval` "sets" an asynchronous task to be executed some time in the future (2000ms in your code). After the call is made, execution immediately continues to the next line. Also, you should use `setTimeout` if you want your task to only run once. `setInterval` causes the task to be executed in an endless "loop" (At least untill `clearInterval` is called).
2. Your `while` condition is redundant. I will never be equal to or higher then 4 since you reset it inside the while block (in the last `if`). That seems intentional, but then there is no reason to have a condition at all (use `while(true)`)

A solution to do what you wanted could be:

```js
var maxPrints = 20; // Otherwise this will never end...

function nextInterval(i) {
  console.log(i == 0 ? 'bar' : 'foo');
  if(--maxPrints > 0)
    setTimeout(function() { nextInterval((i + 1) % 4); }, 2000);
}
nextInterval(0);
```

Or you could do it with a single call to `setInterval` like this:

```js
var maxPrints = 20; // Otherwise this will never end...
var i = 0, interval;

function nextInterval() {
  console.log((i++ % 4) == 0 ? 'bar' : 'foo');
  if(--maxPrints <= 0)
    clearInterval(interval);
}
interval = setInterval(nextInterval, 2000);
```

Comment: Thanks for your pointers. The solution, however, is not working.

Answer (score 1):

The way I would approach this is by making a run list of functions to call in order:

```js
function loopFunctions(functions, delay)
{
    var i = 0;

    return setInterval(function() {
        // call current function
        functions[i]();
        // advance pointer and loop if necessary
        i = (i + 1) % functions.length;
    }, delay);
}

var foo = function() { console.log('foo'); };
var bar = function() { console.log('bar'); };

loopFunctions([foo, foo, foo, bar], 2000);
```

It's relatively easy to populate that array:

```
var fns = Array.apply(null, new Array(3)).map(function() { 
    return foo; 
}).concat([bar]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```js
var i = 0,
  num = 3,
  interval = setInterval(function() {
    if (i < num) {
      console.log('foo')
    } else {
      console.log('bar')
    }

    if (i++ == num) {
      i = 0;
    }
  }, 500);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setinterval to two function, setinterval to one function that call two function conditionally.